# Distributed Transaction SQL Error using Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some database troubles, and can't seem to find a solution anywhere for this specific problem. I'm trying to grab information from a database using a table on the database and comparing it to a table on a linked server

```
[3/7/14 10:10:14:181 EST] 00000021 SystemErr     R org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "EADWH02" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
### The error may involve com.moog.app.weldlog.dao.mybatis.WeldLogMapping.listEmployee-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "EADWH02" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

Here is one of the specific stored procedures that is throwing this error:

```
@workOrder   varchar(25)    = null,
@idPartNumber    varchar(25)    = null
begin   

    IF @workOrder is null       
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 25 WO.WO_NBR, PARTS.PART_NBR
        FROM EADWH02.MEDW.LBR.WO WO
        JOIN EADWH02.MEDW.MFG.PARTS PARTS
        ON PARTS.PART_KEY = WO.PART_KEY
        AND PARTS.SRC_DB_KEY = WO.SRC_DB_KEY
        WHERE   (WO.WO_TYPE_KEY = '2' or WO.WO_TYPE_KEY = '3' or WO.WO_TYPE_KEY = '4' or WO.WO_TYPE_KEY = '5') and          
            (PARTS.PART_NBR like '' + @idPartNumber + '%')
    ELSE IF @idPartNumber is null 
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 25 WO.WO_NBR, PARTS.PART_NBR, dbo.getDescriptions(WO.WO_NBR) as strDescriptions
        FROM EADWH02.MEDW.LBR.WO WO
        JOIN EADWH02.MEDW.MFG.PARTS PARTS
        ON PARTS.PART_KEY = WO.PART_KEY
        AND PARTS.SRC_DB_KEY = WO.SRC_DB_KEY
        WHERE   ((WO.WO_TYPE_KEY = '2' or WO.WO_TYPE_KEY = '3' or WO.WO_TYPE_KEY = '4' or WO.WO_TYPE_KEY = '5') and         
            (WO.WO_NBR like '' + @workOrder))
        ORDER BY WO.WO_NBR  
end
```

((dbo.getDescriptions is a scalar-valued function and works fine))

And here is my xml mapping file in the project:

`<select id="listWorkOrder" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="WorkOrder" resultMap="WorkOrderMap"> {
        call listWorkOrder( #{workOrder, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
                            #{partNumber, jdbcType=VARCHAR})
    }
    </select>`

Any chance anyone knows what's causing this error? This sql stored procedure breaks both on a remote server we're using and on a local server. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Have you checked the DTC configuration on all servers involved in the transaction?

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, but is the MSDTC service running?

Comment: Will double check that now Crispalot, and Mason, a lot of the things I looked up said as much, but I'm honestly a bit unsure where I'm supposed to go to find it.

Comment: Welp, seems that we're going to use a different server for our data, since we don't have permissions to change the current server's settings. Sorry for wasting your guys time, but I appreciate the effort.